# VeeValidate form using data provided by API

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I went through many examples of VeeValidate forms.
All of them seem to focus only on the validation part and they use the initial-values attribute.
As far as I understand this can only use static data but in my case I use async API call in `onMounted` to load an object (with nested objects and arrays).

How do I populate the form with the data from API once it has been loaded?

Answer (score 0):

The way that is closest to normal Vue is to use `v-model` directly on `Field` components.

The [example from the docs](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/api/field/#using-v-model) that is most relevant is this one:

```
<Field type="text" name="name" v-model="name" />
```

Or if you need more complex fields:

```
<Field v-model="name" type="text" name="name" v-slot="{ field }">
  <input v-bind="field">
</Field>
```